# Angular currency editor

Tags: angular, primeng, ngx-mask

I need to make a form control in Angular that supports editing currency values with negative number support and full keyboard support so the user can tab between inputs, type a negative symbol and then enter the value. I have tried ngx-currency, PrimeNG input number and ngx-mask but cannot get exactly what I need.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4qccmy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) of what I have so far.

ngx-currency

```html
<input currencyMask [(ngModel)]="value">
```

PrimeNG Input Number

```html
<p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="value" mode="currency"
  currency="USD" locale="en-US"></p-inputNumber>
```

ngx-mask

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="value" mask="separator" thousandSeparator=","
  prefix="$" [allowNegativeNumbers]="true">
```

*ngx-currency*

you need to type the negative symbol after you have typed the value which is kind of counter intuitive and as soon as you type the negative symbol the cursor goes to the end of the input.

*PrimeNG*

when you type the negative symbol the next number causes the cursor to jump behind the the cents at the end making it completely unusable.

*ngx-mask*

It's usable but I can't figure out how to get the cents to always be 2 decimal places and the minus symbol is after the $ symbol instead of before the $. It is the closest as it is usable but the value showing as $50.5 instead of $50.50 will get it rejected by my product owner.

The control will be used in a spreadsheet style page where tabbing between inputs and entering in the characters -50.50 needs to cause the value to be negative $50 and 50 cents.

Comment: This is driving me crazy, too!

Answer (score 2):

It's quite surprising you can't do such a basic thing with three different libraries...

I'm facing the same issues as you even after reading the docs and tried some tests and I'm curious to see a good answer to your question.

While waiting for that, what you could do is to cheat on the prefix with `ngx-currency`. If the user types minus sign, then update the prefix from '$' to '-$':

HTML

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" mask="separator.2" thousandSeparator="," [prefix]="prefix" [allowNegativeNumbers]="false" (keyup)="updatePrefix($event)">
```

TS

```
updatePrefix(event: any) {
    if (event.key === "-") {
        this.prefix = this.prefix === "$" ? "-$" : "$";
    }
}
```

Check [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jyg7cq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what problem you have with ngx-mask. I've created a sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rz1dkp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

It doesn't put the minus before the `$`. What of the "always" have 2 digits in cents is up to your formatting.

I've achieved 2 digits in the result by using `toFixed(2)`.

So basically you need to transform the output value when the value is printed/submitted. If you were to change have these cents always have 2 digits in user input it might create a bad UX as thing would "jump"

Comment: $-99.5 in the input is the problem

Comment: How exactly? For me it prints `Input value is: "$-99.50"`. If you are talking about the trailing `0` in the input then how do you imagine UX which would edit the value when the user changes it? You could update the value in the input on blur or after some delay when changes cease

Comment: I built my own control to do it on blur.